# LiveValidation - Focus

Tags: jquery, livevalidation

I'm using LiveValidation and I'm just wondering if anyone has had sucsess in setting the focus on the failed input form ready for re-entry...

I've looked at the documentation but can't see anything.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

this is not a live validation option but I ended up with a solution like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Focus first erroneous input
    $("form").on("submit", function(){
        var $self = $(this);

        setTimeout(function() {
            var $fields = $self.find(".LV_invalid_field");

            if ($fields.size() > 0) {
                $fields.get(0).focus();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to do this..

I've just altered the addFieldClass function, with the following:

```
addFieldClass: function(){

    this.removeFieldClass();
    if(!this.validationFailed){
        if(this.displayMessageWhenEmpty || this.element.value != ''){
            if(this.element.className.indexOf(this.validFieldClass) == -1) this.element.className += ' ' + this.validFieldClass;
        }
    }else{
        if(this.element.className.indexOf(this.invalidFieldClass) == -1) this.element.className += ' ' + this.invalidFieldClass;

        //Set Focus On In-Valid Elements
        var id = this.element.id;
        document.getElementById(id).focus();
    }
},
```